# How to sort in Firebase with Multiple priority?

Tags: firebase

I have data like this in Firebase:

```
mainNode
      pictures
           -JJr1PypNhBOCjSIf_0j
                user: user1
                view: 20
           -JJr1PadFxtUs_wCtj2a
                user: user2
                view: 500
      users
           -user1
                name: 'Austin'
           -user2
                name: 'Bucha'
```

and I have two cases.

1. Get Pictures of UserX
2. Show Pictures by Most View

I can get desired result for **case#1** if I run like this and `setPriority` with `userId`

```
new Firebase("https://xxx.firebaseio.com/pictures")
    .startAt('user1')
    .endAt('user1')
    .once('value', show);
```

However, I am lost when I want to get `all pictures sorted by MOST view limit to 10`. 
Since `setPriority` can be used once, how can I get the result for case#2?
Please shed me a light here for better approach and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For pictures of user X, simply store a list (an index) of that user's photos in a separate location:

```
/my_photos/$user_id/$photo_id/<true>
/photos/$photo_id/<data> (with priority for most viewed)
```

Now to fetch the most viewed, use a call like so:

```
new Firebase(URL).child('photos').endAt().limit(10).once('value', function(snap) {
   console.log('most viewed', snap.val());
});
```

And to get the ones belonging to me:

```
new Firebase(URL).child('my_photos/kato').on('child_added', function(indexSnap) {
   new Firebase(URL).child('photos/'+indexSnap.name()).once('value', function(photoSnap) {
      console.log('one of my photos', console.log(photoSnap.val());
   });
});
```

A tool like [FirebaseIndex](https://github.com/Zenovations/FirebaseIndex) or [Firebase.util.join](http://firebase.github.io/firebase-util/) can abstract the process of joining the index and data:

```
var fb = new Firebase(URL);
var joined = new FirebaseIndex( fb.child('my_photos/kato'), fb.child('photos') );
joined.on('child_added', function(snap) {
   console.log('one of my photos', snap.val());
});
```